# reading a text file and counting how many times a word is repeated. Using .split function. Now wants it to ignore case sensitive

Tags: python, split, case-sensitive

Getting the desired output so far.

The program prompts user to search for a word.

user enters it and the program reads the file and gives the output.

'ashwin: 2'

Now i want it to ignore case sensitive. For example, "Ashwin" and "ashwin" both shall return 2, as it contains two ashwin`s  in the text file.

```
def word_count():
    file = "test.txt"
    word = input("Enter word to be searched:")
    k = 0

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            for i in words:
                if i == word:
                    k = k + 1
    print(word + ": " + str(k))


word_count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [lower()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower) to compare the strings in this part `if i.lower() == word.lower():`

For example:

```
def word_count():
    file = "test.txt"
    word = input("Enter word to be searched:")
    k = 0

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            for i in words:
                if i.lower() == word.lower():
                    k = k + 1
    print(word + ": " + str(k))


word_count()
```

Comment: thanks, i tried using .lower before but was using it in the wrong place, thanks.. it solved my problem xD

Answer (score 0):

Use the Counter class from collections that returns an dictionary with key value pairs that could be accessed using `O(1)` time.

```
from collections import Counter

def word_count():
    file = "test.txt"

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
         words = f.read().replace('\n', '').lower().split()
         count = Counter(words)

    word = input("Enter word to be searched:")
    print(word, ":", count.get(word.lower()))
```

Comment: You should lower the word too

Answer (score 0):

You can either use .lower on the line and word to eliminate case.
Or you can use the built-in re module.

len(re.findall(word, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE))